# VBA Project - Wait for ExecuteMso("StatusDate") to return data

Tags: vba, ms-project

I'm running a macro that needs the status date. I am using `ActiveProject.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("StatusDate")` and the macro just keeps executing before I set the status date on Project 2016. How can I code to wait for the date to be entered?

Answer (score 0):

I can see how practical it would be to use that command, but there are the consequences you have found.

If you are ready to spend another click on setting the Status Date you can just add a dummy MsgBox dialog after your command:

```
ActiveProject.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("StatusDate")
MsgBox "Status Date set"
```

...or have you found another solution meanwhile?

Comment: thanks. I am using your solution. The only issue is when I press the cancel button when setting the status date. It pops up the `msgbox`anyway.

Comment: Yes. Another unwanted side effect. :-)

Unfortunately it seems impossible to get the good old date picker for Project, but of course a simple form with one text box and two buttons could work (depending how you set the Status Date*)

In the main code to have these lines:

`Sub StatusDateUpdate()
    'In case you usually set the Status Date to today*
    frmStatusDate.txtStatusDate.Value = Date
    
    frmStatusDate.Show

End Sub`

*You could add some function to set the Status Date for tomorrow, next Wednesday etc..